# Database function that takes as input date and time

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-function

Looking for a bit of guidance here on an SQL function.

I have this table here:

```
CREATE TABLE appointments
(
    patient varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    doctor varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    apt_date date NOT NULL,
    apt_start time NOT NULL,
    apt_end time NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pk_appointments PRIMARY KEY (patient, apt_date)
);
```

I'm looking for a function that takes as input a date and time and returns the number of appointments active at a given date and time.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below PostgreSQL function activeAppointments() which takes input date and time and returns the number of appointments active at a given date and time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.activeappointments(
    ondate date,
    fromtime time without time zone,
    totime time without time zone)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare
    total integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) into total FROM appointments 
   where apt_date = ondate and apt_start >= fromTime and apt_end <= toTime;
   RETURN total;
END;
$BODY$;
```

I have taken above mentioned "appointments" table and inserted below sample data to it.

```
insert into appointments values ('Patient001', 'Doc001', '01-JAN-2021','120000','130000');
insert into appointments values ('Patient002', 'Doc001', '01-JAN-2021','133000','143000');
insert into appointments values ('Patient003', 'Doc001', '01-JAN-2021','150000','160000');
```

- Total records inserted 3.

```
select count(1) from appointments;
```

- To run the function, please use the below script.

```
SELECT activeAppointments('01-JAN-2021', '120000', '150000'); --2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why a function? A simple SQL query seems enough:

```
select count(*)
from appointments
where apt_date = date '2021-04-30'
  and time '14:00' between apt_start and apt_end
```